# Invisible icons in support action mode on Honeycomb

Tags: android

When using support action mode на **honeycomb** can't see icons for actions. On 2.3 and 4.0 it visible. Action button actually exists, click working but icon is invisible.
Snippet from MainActivity

```
  private ActionMode.Callback callback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mode.setTitle("Selected");
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_mode, menu);               
          return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
          return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "item " + item.getTitle());
          mode.finish();
          return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
          toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          actionMode = null;
        }

      };

private void enableActionMode() {
            actionMode = startSupportActionMode(callback);  

        }
```

action_mode.xml from menu folder

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.neptunisima.learncarlogos.MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_add_favorite"
     android:title="@string/action_logo_grid"          
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_stop_white_48dp"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal800</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/teal900</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/teal800 </item> 
 </style>   
</resources>
```